# How to remove \xa0 from soup in beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, encoding

I am currently using Beautifulsoup to parse the HTML code of a webpage.

To get the text from an element, I use the ".text" attribute:

```
soup.find('p', {'class': 'example'}).text
```

But the problem is that sometimes I get `"\xa0"` in the result:

```
"some text «\xa0text\xa0»"
```

I tried using the "replace" function:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source.replace('\xa0', ' '), "lxml")
```

NOTE: I don't want to have to use a function for every single string I parse, I would like to have the soup already purged from those characters from the beginning.

Comment: The problem is that the HTML source probably contains `&nbsp;`, not the literal `\xa0`. Try replacing that instead, or as well.

Comment: Perfect! The little nuance I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the HTML source probably contains `&nbsp;`, not the literal `\xa0`. Try replacing that instead, or as well.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(
    driver.page_source.replace(
        '&nbsp;', ' ').replace('\xa0', ' '), "lxml")
```